# Проблема с пониманием алгоритма Монтгомери

Tags: алгоритм, математика, дискретная-математика

Возникла необходимость разобраться в алгоритме Монтгомери. При изучении статьи на википедии (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8) столкнулся с проблемой, конкретно в данном выражении:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему данное равенство верно? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Согласно написанному до этого в статье: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Куда пропадает mod n при подстановке в равенство  [image: введите сюда описание изображения] и [image: введите сюда описание изображения] . Заранее благодарен за ответ

Answer (score 2):

Потому что

```
((a mod n) * (b mod n)) mod n = (a*b) mod n
```

**mod n** - это по сути взятие остатка при делении на n. Если  a=kn+q и b=ln+r, то первая часть превращается в

```
q*r mod n
```

а вторая

```
(kn+q)*(ln+r) mod n = (n*(kln+ql+kr)+ q*r) mod n = q*r mod n
```